# Java currency formatter: Force to format using currency symbol

Tags: java, currency, formatter

I use the spring currency formatter to format a value based on currency code

```
public String format(Number number, String currencyCode)
{
    CurrencyFormatter formatter = new CurrencyFormatter();
    formatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(currencyCode));
    return formatter.print(number, Locale.getDefault());        
}
```

So if I call it as format(10, "GBP") then I want the value back as £10.00, no matter what the locale is.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you display a currency, you need two pieces of info: the currency code, and the locale for which you are displaying a result. For example, when you display USD in the en_US locale, you want it to show $, but in the en_AU locale, you want it to show as US$ (because Australia's currency is also called "dollars" and they use the $ symbol for AUD).

The issue you've hit is that the stock Java currency formatters stink when you are displaying a currency in its "non-primary" locale. That is, pretty much everyone in the US would rather see £ and € when showing pounds and euros, but the stock Java libraries show "GBP" and "EUR" when showing those currencies in the en_US locale.

I got around this with the following piece of code. I essentially specify my own symbols to use when displaying international currencies:

```
public static NumberFormat newCurrencyFormat(Currency currency, Locale displayLocale) {
    NumberFormat retVal = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(displayLocale);
    retVal.setCurrency(currency);

    //The default JDK handles situations well when the currency is the default currency for the locale
    if (currency.equals(Currency.getInstance(displayLocale))) {
        return retVal;
    }

    //otherwise we need to "fix things up" when displaying a non-native currency
    if (retVal instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) retVal;
        String correctedI18NSymbol = getCorrectedInternationalCurrencySymbol(currency, displayLocale);
        if (correctedI18NSymbol != null) {
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols(); //this returns a clone of DFS
            dfs.setInternationalCurrencySymbol(correctedI18NSymbol);
            dfs.setCurrencySymbol(correctedI18NSymbol);
            decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

private static String getCorrectedInternationalCurrencySymbol(Currency currency, Locale displayLocale) {
    ResourceBundle i18nSymbolsResourceBundle =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("correctedI18nCurrencySymbols", displayLocale);
    if (i18nSymbolsResourceBundle.containsKey(currency.getCurrencyCode())) {
        return i18nSymbolsResourceBundle.getString(currency.getCurrencyCode());
    } else {
        return currency.getCurrencyCode();
    }
}
```

Then I have my properties file (correctedI18nCurrencySymbols.properties) where I specify currency symbols to use:

```
# Note that these are the currency symbols to use for the specified code when displaying in a DIFFERENT locale than
# the home locale of the currency. This file can be edited as needed. In addition, if in some case one specific locale
# would use a symbol DIFFERENT than the standard international one listed here, then an additional properties file
# can be added making use of the standard ResourceBundle loading algorithm. For example, if we decided we wanted to
# show US dollars as just $ instead of US$ when in the UK, we could create a file i18nCurrencySymbols_en_GB.properties
# with the entry USD=$
ARS=$AR
AUD=AU$
BOB=$b
BRL=R$
CAD=CAN$
CLP=Ch$
COP=COL$
CRC=\u20A1
HRK=kn
CZK=K\u010D
DOP=RD$
XCD=EC$
EUR=\u20AC
GTQ=Q
GYD=G$
HNL=L
HKD=HK$
HUF=Ft
INR=\u20B9
IDR=Rp
ILS=\u20AA
JMD=J$
JPY=JP\u00A5
KRW=\u20A9
NZD=NZ$
NIO=C$
PAB=B/.
PYG=Gs
PEN=S/.
PHP=\u20B1
PLN=\u007A\u0142
RON=lei
SGD=S$
ZAR=R
TWD=NT$
THB=\u0E3F
TTD=TT$
GBP=\u00A3
USD=US$
UYU=$U
VEF=Bs
VND=\u20AB
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Spring, but the following appears to be the issue: `Locale.getDefault()`. Instead, try using one of the static instances defined on the `Locale` class.

Comment: No, my question was I do not want to format using locale. I just want to say give me symbol for Pound Sterling and it should return me £ without me saying Locale.UK.

Comment: How will Java know how to format it without a Locale? That is the vehicle through which you specify settings such as currency symbols, decimal separators, and other formatting settings. Otherwise, you need to use manual string manipulation to do what you want.